# How to render interlaced video (2.8)

Tags: rendering, video

How can I render my scene to interlaced video, I don't want progressive.
I use latest blender version 2.8. In 2.7 there was a "Fields" option somewhere but I cant find it in 2.8

Answer (score 0):

Apparently they removed the option. It was an option of old crt tvs. but even today there are broadcast channels that use 1080i. Other programs like Cinema 4d still have the option. Professional camcorders still record at 2160i. It is still a useful option to decrease the data flow. I don't know why they removed it.